# Who would say “letters of love” as opposed to “love letters”?

Tags: british-english, syntactic-analysis

From what part of the world would a person refer to *love letters* as *letters of love*?

Comment: From any part, probably. There's nothing wrong with altering a cliche to freshen it up a bit.

Comment: Anything exciting you found yourself? Any homework done?

Comment: Anybody who wants to say a _da da da DA_ rhythm rather than a _DA da da_ rhythm. A Beethoven fan, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I looked at all the blurbs for *letters of love* 1800–1811 book links at [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=love+letters%2Cletters+of+love&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) (for *love letters,letters of love*) and all of them are English (not American, not Australian, etc).  At that time, it was a phrase used comparatively frequently by Richard Steele and Joseph Addison in their *Spectator* or *Tatler*; and used as frequently in like publications of the time.

More recently (ie, [1972–2008](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22letters%20of%20love%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1972,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en)) *letters of love* is used mostly in titles of books, and those books appear to be from a variety of places:  USA, Israel, Germany, Russia etc.   But note that incidence of *letters of love* now is minuscule compared to that of *love letters*, whereas in the early 1800's it was about half.